# javascript firefox popup

Tags: javascript

I would like to open a new tab (or window, depending on the user's browser settings) with javascript when the user clicks on a link. I have seen other sites who do that, without being flagged as popups by firefox. My link is flagged as a popup though. Maybe it's because it is necessary that the domain stay the same (which is not my case) ?
Is there a way to prevent my link to be flagged as popup, seeing as the new tab event is triggered by a mouse click ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give the markup/code for your link?

Comment: Well it's window.open(url), where url has a different domain name than the one the user is currently in.

Comment: if same domain window.open works then why not open a popup first in same domain and then redirect it from that page to the new url.

Comment: you're right, it makes sense :). I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution ? On the other hand, I am not sure this is a domain issue, I was merely stating the facts. Actually what I would rather do is to give the user the opportunity to either open it in a new tab (or window), or stay in the same tab. Firefox allows that choice, with middle click to open a new tab. Unfortunately, the middle click doesn't work for me, because the html a tag is <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="f()"/>, and middle clicking just brings a new tab whose url is javascript:void(0). Any way around that ?

Comment: How about considering not using a popup in your design? They are blocked for a reason: users don't like them.

Comment: Actually it is for my own and only use. I am trying to create a greasemonkey script to improve my user experience on a remote site. And I wouldn't consider it a popup, because it is triggered by a click on a link. But you're right, I'd rather have the option to middle click instead. Unfornately I don't know how to do that with javascript. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would probably do -- depending on the exact requirements -- is, instead of setting an `onclick` handler, set an `onmouseup` handler, and instead of having the handler open the link, have the handler set the link's `href` -- and *not* override the browser's default behavior. (That last part isn't actually important behavior-wise, since there's no major default on-mouse-up behavior, but it's important readability-wise!) Then, after the handler finishes, the browser will act just as if the user had clicked on a normal link with that `href`: assuming typical Firefox settings, a left-click will open the link in the same tab, a middle-click will open it in a new tab, and a right-click will open a context-menu with options such as "Open Link in New Window" and "Open Link in New Tab".

Comment: Yes this seems to be exactly what I want. Thanks for the idea. I'm going to try it now and report here if I face any issues.

Comment: Err... after some thought there is something I find obscure about your idea: if onmouseup is supposed to initialize the href, then won't it mean I have to press twice on the link to actually open it?

Comment: No, because the `onmouseup` handler is called before the normal link-handling logic happens. By the time Firefox goes, "oh, hey, he just middle-clicked on a link, I should open it in a new tab", the `href` will already have been changed. (I tested this before posting, by creating a local HTML page consisting of just `<a href="#" onmouseup="this.href='http://example.com/'">bar</a>`. If you want to see how this behaves, without having to massively refactor your code first, you can try the same test.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "target" attribute of the link itself:

```
<a target=_blank href='whatever'>Click Me!</a>
```

to open a link in a new window/tab.

Comment: Will that always override a popup blocker (at least, within reason)?

Comment: Well who knows what people have built into their browsers (via add-ons or whatever), but generally an explicit user action like a mouse click on a link will allow a page to do something like that.

Comment: True enough; I don't know enough about how popup blockers work to comment, I suppose. Just that *some* sites seem to have this down (no matter the settings...). `:s`

Comment: I'm also at my upvote limit (4 minutes left), or else I would upvote. I was going to add this as a comment, since I wasn't sure if it was "right" or not.

Comment: I think it's "_blank" with quotes. But it doesn't seem to work for me, it stays on the page, nothing happens. Ultimately this is however not what I want. I would rather give the user (me) the opportunity to either open the link on a new tab (window) or stay in the current page. Middle clicking does that for simple links. But this one is of the form <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="f()"/>, and if I middle click on it, it opens a tab whose url is javascript:void(0). Any way around that ?

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution if it's just going to be you using it is allowing popups on that site. You can configure firefox like so: http://malektips.com/firefox_0003.html

Comment: I will be the only one using my solution indeed, but the site I want to apply my solution in is not mine, and therefore I wouldn't want to allow this site to bring me popups :). But in any case popup was probably a poor choice of words. This isn't really the behaviour I want. I tried to make my needs clearer in my other comments. Basically I want to be able to either make the link a "popup" (new tab) or not, depending on the type of click I make (left or middle, ctrl click, ..., as with normal links). The difficulty here resides in the fact that it's a js function and not a normal link.

Comment: what site exactly? I could help more if I knew the site so I could actually test against something